# $lookup to an array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I have two collections.
**USERS**

```
{
  "_id" : "myid",
  "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-12-26T14:00:11.624Z"),
  "email" : "testing@gmail.com"
}
```

**GROUPS**

```
{
  "_id" : "myidgroup",
  "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-12-26T14:00:11.624Z"),
  "name" : "student"
  "userIds": ["myUserId1", "myUserId2"]
}
```

I want to do a `$lookup` to the **groups** collection to get all users with groups

```
|      email          |     groups.      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|  testing@gmail.com  |   student        |
```

I expected output like this:

```
[
  {
     _id: "myUserId"
    email: "testing@gmail.com",
    groups: [
              { 
                "_id": "myGroupId",
                "name": "student"
              }
            ]

  }
]
```

I know we can do it with new `$lookup` in mongodb 3.6 and above but I am using mongodb 3.4.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what have you tried?, can you add your tries in your question.

Comment: I am using `$match` to get users, but I have no idea when I ```$lookup``` to the groups of users because in the **groups**  _userIds_ is an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$lookup` join with `groups` collection, pass `_id` as `localField` and pass `userIds` as `foreignField`
- `$project` to show required fields

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "groups",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "userIds",
      "as": "groups"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      email: 1,
      "groups._id": 1,
      "groups.name": 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bVZ8jkgk7ah)

Comment: have no idea that $lookup can do this with different type of data, thanks!